# Python/Numpy find length variable spans

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, numpy, scipy

Consider a numpy array of shape `(n,)` <s>that is monotonically increasing.</s>

```
X = np.array([2,3,7,19,110,112,120,140,161])
```

My problem is to extract efficiently every span `(i,j)` such that:

```
X[i:j].sum() >= v and X[i:j-1].sum() < v
```

I'm not sure about this formalization. In other words I need "the smallest possible spans that sum above v". I guess that another way to put it is "all the spans that sum above v and that are not subset of another span".

So far the best I've done is based on two nested for loops:

```
def variable_length_spans(X, v):
    n, = X.shape
    for i in xrange(0, n):
        sum_ = 0
        for j in xrange(i, n):
            sum_ += X[j]
            if sum_ >= v:
                yield (i,j+1)
                break
```

Which gives:

```
list(variable_length_spans(X,10))
[(0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9)]
```

It must be a more efficient / elegant way to do that. Yet, I can find out how. Any proposal will be warmly appreciated!

F.

## Update #1: timings

With a 20K random elements (results are averaged over 10 runs):

- variable_length_spans: 0.009332 sec
- davis_spans: **0.009259** sec
- spans_broadcast: 1.896222 sec

With 1M random elements (results are averaged over 50 runs):

- variable_length_spans: **0.528101** sec
- davis_broadcast: 0.534576 sec

Comment: Typo, sorry, I meant X instead of dt. There is no return because variable_length_spans is a generator (mind the yield statement).

Comment: Appreciate the edits!

Comment: So, does the loopy code listed in the question really work to achieve the pseudo code : `X[j] - X[i] >= v and X[j-1] - X[i] < v`? That loopy code has bunch of summations, which I don't see in the pseudo code.

Comment: Ah right, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: That shape isn't `(n, 1)`; this is a 1-dimensional array.

Comment: I posted an answer which does the same thing as your code, but I don't believe your code does exactly what you're asking for. Specifically, you might allow the spans (3, 6) and (4, 6), even though one is included in the other.

Comment: You're right, I updated my question to be more specific. A span should not be a subset of another span. Yet partial inclusion is not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is a quadratic algorithm, and it can be done in linear time, as follows:

```
def spans(X, v):
    n, = X.shape
    i = 0
    total = 0
    for j in xrange(0, n):
        total += X[j]
        while total >= v:
            yield (i, j+1)
            total -= X[i]
            i += 1
```

Comment: Form what I understand your version and mine have the same complexity (thanks to the break statement I use in the inner for loop). Am I right ?

Comment: Not in the worst case. For example, suppose n = 100 and that X = [1, 1, 1, ...., 1000000000]. Then your solution takes about n(n-1)/2 loop iterations and mine takes about 2n.

Comment: Ok, got it, that's better than my solution.

Comment: Yet, both have quite identical run times. Would it exist an even better solution?

Comment: They don't have identical run times. Linear is a significant improvement over quadratic.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding. On what basis are you saying they have identical run times?

Comment: Both of these are generator functions. You'll notice that if you increase the size of X it still barely changes the running time. Throw a list() call around the calls to the generators. When I did this for len(X) = 1000, I got an improvement by about a factor of 200.

Comment: Oups! I indeed forgot to consume the iterators ... that's terribly dumb, my bad! I've also got how you managed to be in linear time. The worst case scenario is quite helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Vectorized approach based on [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
# Get cumulative summations
cumsums = X.cumsum()

# Elementwise subtractions between cumsums & its one place shifted version
diffs = cumsums[:,None] - np.append(0,cumsums[:-1])

# Detect cumulative summation span check
mask = diffs >= v

# Get valid mask for later selection purpose
valid = mask.any(0)

# Get first trigger indices
max_idx = np.argmax(mask,0)+1

# Concatenate row indices alongwith trigger ones for final output
out = np.column_stack((np.arange(max_idx.size),max_idx))[valid]
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [212]: X
Out[212]: array([  2,   3,   7,  19, 110, 112, 120, 140, 161])

In [213]: v
Out[213]: 10

In [214]: out
Out[214]: 
array([[0, 3],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 5],
       [5, 6],
       [6, 7],
       [7, 8],
       [8, 9]])
```

Comment: The solution is very elegant, but the `diffs = cumsums[:,None] - cumsums` might blowup my memory if X grows.

Comment: @FrançoisKawala That's right, it comes with the inherent nature of `vectorization` that requires sufficient memory to do things in one go. How big is your `X`?

Comment: My X is about 1e5. I've timed (timeit) our approaches and it seems that the nested loop is faster. (10x average, X.shape==(1e4,)) **variable_length_spans**: 0.004613 /
**spans_broadcast**: 0.456812. Does it make sense ?

Comment: @FrançoisKawala Yes, if the input data is such that you are breaking early in the summations, then you won't see any/much benefit with vectorized methods. With this vectorized solution, we are creating all the summations and the spans(differentiations) and then checking in one go, but sadly not benefiting in your case.

Comment: Ok, that good to know! I naively though that what ever I'll do with for loops would be slower than vectorized methods. I've tested with random values drawn accordingly to my data, hence I guess I'll stick with iterative approach for this one.

Comment: @FrançoisKawala Yup, I second that!

Comment: Thanks for your propositions! greatly appreciated !